How to make a button stay at the bottom of a dynamically resizing BottomSheet in .NET MAUI?
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application and I have a BottomSheet with a button that should always be at the bottom. The BottomSheet initially takes up 60% of the screen height, but it can also expand to fullscreen. The problem is that when the BottomSheet is at 60% height, the button is not visible because it is positioned based on the full height of the BottomSheet.
Here is a simplified version of my XAML code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<the49:BottomSheet x:Class="Helix.UI.Mobile.Modules.ProductModule.Views.ProductViews.BottomSheetViews.ProductStockLocationBottomSheetView"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:Helix.UI.Mobile.Helpers.FontAwesomeHelper"
                   xmlns:the49="https://schemas.the49.com/dotnet/2023/maui"
                   xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                   x:Name="this"
                   Padding="0,20,0,0"
                   BackgroundColor="White"
                   HandleColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                   HasBackdrop="True"
                   HasHandle="True">
    <the49:BottomSheet.Detents>
        <the49:FullscreenDetent />
        <!--<the49:ContentDetent />-->
        <the49:RatioDetent Ratio="0.60" />
    </the49:BottomSheet.Detents>
    <the49:BottomSheet.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding GetDataCommand}" EventName="Loaded" />
    </the49:BottomSheet.Behaviors>
  <AbsoluteLayout>
    <Grid Padding="0,10,0,0"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
          RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto"
          RowSpacing="10">
        <!--#region Title-->
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Large"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Text="Stok Yeri Seçimi"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <!--#endregion-->
      <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... </CollectionView>
      <Border Grid.Row="2"
        Padding="10,0"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 1, 1, AutoSize"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        StrokeThickness="0"
        VerticalOptions="End">
        <Button BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Text="Tamam">
          <Button.GestureRecognizers>
             <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
          </Button.GestureRecognizers>
        </Button>

     </Border>
   </Grid>
 </AbsoluteLayout>
</the49:BottomSheet>


I want the "Confirm" button to always be visible at the bottom of the BottomSheet, regardless of its height. How can I achieve this?
I've tried using AbsoluteLayout with various LayoutBounds and LayoutFlags settings, but I can't get the button to stay at the bottom when the BottomSheet is resized. Any suggestions?
Full Content:

60% Content:


Your button is a child of the bottom sheet and as such will be moved up and down relative to its parent. You would either need to specify an absolute position and update that relative to the bottom sheet every time it's moved (this may cause flickering) or you have to take the button out of the bottom sheet and place it in an AbsoluteLayout, so that it isn't a child of the bottom sheet and doesn't move with it.

You could probably also solve this by subscribing to the SelectedDetent's property change event and update the position of the button according to that.
